# Распределение задач по процессам python multiprocessing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, multiprocessing

У меня есть задача: По названию найти кучу youtube видео (пишу discord бота). Для этого я использую `youtubesearchpython`, но обработка 100 песен может затянуться +- на 2 минуты, что меня не устраивает, и я решил распределить по 20 треков в 5 процессов с помощью `multiprocessing`. Проблема в том, что я запускаю `multiprocessing.Pool` не из главного файла (`run.py` => `my_bot.load_extension('Bot')` => `import parser.Parser` => `multiprocessing.Pool`) из за чего у меня запускается 5 копий бота. Я слышал, что нужно использовать `if __name__ == "__main__":`, но в моём случае это не работает (так как файл не main). Как запустить только нужную мне функцию в 5 процессах?

P.S. Вот мой код:

```
    async def get_songs(songs: Tuple[str, ...], *, by: str) -> list:
        result = []
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
            step = len(songs) // 5
            args = [{"songs": songs[index: index + step], "by": by} for index in range(0, len(songs), step)]
            for res in pool.map(get_song_process, args):
                result.extend(res)
        return result
```

P.S.2: У меня была идея написать отдельный файл и в нём уже разбивать задачи на процессы, но мне кажется здесь есть решение лучше

Comment: "из за чего у меня запускается 5 копий бота" Итересно, это как?

Comment: multiprocessing 5 раз запускает файл, который запускает бота(от этого спасает `if __name__ == "__main__":`, но я его использовать не могу, так как файл, где я вызываю Pool не главный), а мне нужно, чтобы он 5 раз запускал функцию

Comment: функция get_song_process это логика бота?

Comment: Не важно главный файл или нет, важно чтобы весь код, который не должен лишний раз запускаться сидел в таких `if`-ах. У вас не виндоуз случайно? Там нужно ещё `freezesupport` использовать.

Comment: @СергейШашко, Да

Comment: @CrazyElf, Работает! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не важно главный файл или нет, важно чтобы весь код, который не должен лишний раз запускаться сидел в таких if-ах. У вас не виндоуз случайно? Там нужно ещё freezesupport использовать. – CrazyElf